# Series formulas

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone explain the formula and give me a link. thanks!
[image]

So last time I checked the formula for finding sums with a specific ratio would be

$\text{sum} = \large \frac{a}{1 - r}$

wherein "$a$" is the first term and "$r$" is the ratio between the terms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are using the formula for the [sum of a geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series)
$$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n=\frac{a(r^{n+1}-1)}{r-1}\qquad \left(\text{which is equal to }\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}\right)$$
which follows from simply multiplying:
$$\begin{align*}(a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n)(r-1)&=\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\,\,ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{n+1}\\
&\hphantom{=}-(a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ ar^n)\\[0.05in]
&=-a+ar^{n+1}\\[0.05in]
&=a(r^{n+1}-1)\end{align*}$$
The formula you are thinking of is the formula for the sum of the entire series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n=\frac{a}{1-r},\qquad |r|<1$$
You can see there is a relationship between these two formulas. If the number $r$ is strictly between $1$ and $-1$, then letting $n$ "go to infinity", the number $r^{n+1}$ will become $0$, which turns the expression
$$\frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r}$$
into
$$\frac{a}{1-r}.$$

Comment: So I use the other formula as long as the absolute value of r is greater than 1 right?

Comment: You can use the first formula for any $n$ and any $r$ other than $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks. Last question. Ive seen a formula somewhere before using R^n instead of R^(n+1) so whats the difference?

Comment: They are likely only summing the first $n-1$ terms, which the first formula demonstrates is equal to
$$a+ar+\cdots+ar^{n-1}=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

Comment: By the way, you can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 1):

The sum they have given is the sum of an infinite geometric progression. 
Sum to infinity = $\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1r} = \frac{a+ar^2}{1-r} = \frac{a}{1-r} - \frac{ar^n}{1-r}$

Now from $\frac{a}{1-r} - \frac{ar^n}{1-r}$ where $|r| <1$ if we let n tend to infinity we get $\frac{ar^n}{1-r} = 0$

Therefore the sum of an infinite series is $\frac{a}{1-r} - 0 = \frac{a}{1-r}$

Whereas what you are thinking of is the sum to n terms.